# Package missing from Synaptic package manager

Tags: software-installation, 32-bit

**UPDATE:** my issue has apparently been resolved, and it's astoundingly simple. It turns out that "wine32:i386" is automatically fetched from the repository when installing the "wine32-preloader:i386" package, and I should've just done that to begin with.

I have an offline laptop and another online one. So some days ago I tried to perform a software update on the offline system with debian packages that I downloaded using Cami Cri Cube, which is an portable package manager, and ended up with a bunch of broken packages. I realized that all the broken packages were 32 bit applications and, thinking that I probably don't need them on my 64 bit system, I deleted them to resolve the "broken" issue.

Unfortunately, it seems like I deleted some important packages, among which is the wine32:i386 package, needed to run 32 bit windows applications.

So I then went to reinstall that package, but discovered that this package did not appear in Synaptic. Thinking that this was due to missing repository, I transferred the repo sources list from my online computer, since both systems are running Ubuntu Bionic, and restarted Synaptic.

However I still could not locate the wine32 package in the package list (and I'm sure there are others that aren't listed).

Finally I ran this command on the offline computer:

```
apt-get policy wine32:i386
```

and discovered that this package does in fact have an installation candidate from '500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages'. So it seemed that the issue isn't due to lacking a repository, but with Synaptic's configuration, since I had already selected all of the repositories available, but it still doesn't include all the packages available to apt-get.

Lastly, when trying to install wine32 using apt-get (obviously "trying" because apt-get doesn't work offline) I'm notified that installing wine32 will render a number of existing packages "unnecessary", and that they can be removed. The packages in question are:

libf2fs0 libllvm7 libx11-xcb1:i386 linux-headers-4.15.0-38 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic

I'm not very knowledgeable with Linux, but removing these packages will free up a whooping 230MB so I'm pretty sure I shouldn't mess with them.